# Read head of a STANDARD Turing machine

Tags: turing-machines

In classes it has been explained to us that for a Turing machine to be standard it needs an infinite tape in both directions, a reading head and transitions, where the reading head can move to the left or to the right.

I am currently doing an exercise where I use $R^2$ moves to solve it, that is, once the head reads and writes, it moves twice to the right, that's where my question arises.

If the possible movement in the reading head of a standard Turing machine is $R$ and $L$.
If we used: $R^2, R^3, ..., R^n$ (and the same for $L$), could we still consider it a STANDARD Turing machine?

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here so I'm just learning how to ask these questions to keep things moving :). I hope that this modification complies with what was requested.

Comment: I'm not aware of any standard definition of what a STANDARD Turing machine is. But if I were inventing a definition, I wouldn't be inclined to allow multi-step moves, because (1) I haven't seen them in anyone's official definition of Turing machines and (2) multi-step moves can be easily simulated by one-step moves.